# Filtering unique value to display unique username in Messaging Inbox

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to filter the receiverID such that I will get only unique receiverID. Below is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InboxCollectionViewCell
    cell.inboxMessage.text = chats[indexPath.row].receiverID
    return cell
}



    func loadPosts() {
    let senderIDNumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let chatsRef = db.collection("chats")
    chatsRef.whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            for document in documents {
                let messageText = document.data()["message"] as? String
                let senderIDNumber = document.data()["senderID"] as? String
                let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String
                let timestamp = document.data()["timestamp"] as? String
                let conversationsCounter = document.data()["conversationsCounter"] as? Int
                let chat = Chat(messageTextString: messageText!, senderIDNumber: senderIDNumber!, receiverIDNumber: receiverIDNumber!, timeStampString: timestamp!, conversationsCounterInt: conversationsCounter!)
                self.chats.append(chat)
                print(self.chats)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to filter so that my inboxMessage will display unique users? I'm using Firebase/Firestore as my database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to group the results by their recipients. There is no such group by clause in Firestore's query API. You will have to loop over all messages yourself, and group them client-side.

```
chatsRef.whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: senderIDNumber!)
    .order(by: "receiverID")
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        ...
        let lastReceiverID = "";
        for document in documents {
            ...
            let receiverIDNumber = document.data()["receiverID"] as? String

            if receiverIDNumber != lastReceiverId {
              // TODO: do something with receiverIDNumber
            }
            lastReceiverId = receiverIDNumber
        }
```

In fact, your data model currently looks like you have a single, long list of chat messages between all users, which feels like a very direct translation from a relational data model for chat.

In NoSQL databases, you'll typically want to model your data a bit closer to how your app actually needs it. For example, it seems like you're trying to display all messages for a given sender. In that case, consider storing those messages in a separate collection. E.g. if you have a top-level `/users` collection already, you could have the messages they sent in a `sent` subcollection under there: `/users/$uid/sent`.

For more on data modeling considerations, see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and Todd's video series on Cloud Firestore ([episode 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ) and [episode 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI)).